# How to difference a data set with both continuous & categorical features

Tags: python, time-series, difference

I have a minor doubt suppose my data has a continuous time series(non stationary) & other categorical variables (which are already encoded). Under that circumstance what is the best way to difference the data ? Because categorical data are not differenced but they have to be used while training the model.

I am trying to build an LSTM model so any help is much appreciated.

The data that I am currently using is at daily level & for the sake of illustration I have considered only a univariate scenario (ignoring the variable Var1 & applied differencing only to the variable "TS"

```
TS       Var1
15000     1
14000     1
16000     0

raw_values = daily_data_dummies_V2.values
interval=1
diff = list()
for i in range(interval, len(raw_values)):
    value = raw_values[i] - raw_values[i - interval]
    diff.append(value)

# rescale values to -1, 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(diff)

X = entireData[:,:-1,:]
y = entireData[:,1:,:]


from keras.layers import merge, Input, Dense, TimeDistributed, Lambda        
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.layers import Dropout

# design network
model = Sequential()


model.add(LSTM(150, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(1, None, 1),   
return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=5000, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

previous_inputs=X

model.reset_states() 

predictions = model.predict(previous_inputs)
```

Then I have predicted the entire data & would like to use the last prediction to predict ahead.In doing so I will have to revert the scaling & revert the differencing. Not sure how will I adjust the loop to do the same:

## first, let set the model's states (it's important for it to know the previous trends)

predictions = model.predict(previous_inputs) #this creates states

```
#future predictions
 future = []
 currentStep = predictions[:,-1:,:] #last step from the previous    

  prediction

for i in range(31):
    currentStep = model.predict(currentStep)
    one=currentStep[0]
    two=scaler.inverse_transform(one)
    three=raw_values[-1]+two
    future.append(three)
```

Comment: How is your data loaded? What libraries are you using to work with it? Can we see a sample of the code in question, so that we can answer in a way that helps you with this particular situation?

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy  I have added the code thanks for your response.